# How can an activty and a service write to DB at the same time?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, locking, share

I have an app that has an IntentService that runs once in a while. If both of them run together the SQL statements that write to the database trip over each other ( datbase is locked error ) and are crashing the app.

Is there way for both the activity and the service somehow share the same database connection?

Comment: Use a content provider, and make sure you use a shared `SQLiteDatabase`. ContentProviders are not thread-safe; you need to ensure the locking happens (i.e. allow `SQLiteDatabase` to do that for you).

Answer (score 4):

1. As Falmarri suggests, you can use a content provider.
2. Synchronize access using standard Java thread synchronization options (e.g., `java.util.concurrent`, `synchronized` keyword).
3. The activity should not be writing to the database. The activity should be sending an `Intent` to the `IntentService` and have *it* write to the database.

Comment: I agree totally. Option 3 also avoids jankiness when I/O takes some time. Writes to NAND can take a long time (as in 300ms or so), and the Activity won't react to user input in that time.